# How to convert an object into individual paths in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, live-trace

In illustrator I have imported and traced an image as below:

[image]

I am now trying to split this object into its four base shapes so I can change the fill of the blue parts. I thought trace would convert the object into four paths but it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Tracing image first you have to **expand** that image. then you can ungroup object by right click. After that, you can able to edit the objects individually.[image]

Comment: An image speaks a thousand words. The info bar was missing from my ui which is why I missed the obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Image Trace, the resulting vector objects are grouped by default by Illustrator. You can either

1. Ungroup them (right-click the objects, and then select "Ungroup"). After that, you should be able to edit the objects individually.

or

2. Double-click on one path to isolate and modify it. After the desired edits, you can exit isolation mode by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>. The paths will remain grouped.