# Illustrator: Convert shapes to path and change color fill?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, live-trace, tracing

I've been using `Fireworks` for a long time as a recreational user but now I'm moving to Illustrator, so please bear with me.

I have this simple image with several shapes. I want to "convert" each of these shapes into a path and then change the color fill and the size of each path. The end-result would be 6 separate paths that I can play with.

I found this [How to convert an object into individual paths in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109673/how-to-convert-an-object-into-individual-paths-in-illustrator)), but I don't know what *tracing* is.

With Fireworks I only had to use the *Magic Wand* , right-click, and "Convert to Path".

Is Illustrator the appropriate tool for this?

[image]

Comment: This question may be more helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25165/how-to-convert-a-signature-from-jpg-to-vector-strokes

Comment: Or this one: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/convert-a-line-drawing-from-raster-to-vector

Comment: You can do the same in photoshop. Appart for autotracing theres not much illustrator does to bitmaps. Anyway phostoshop is same paradigm of software to fireworks. Illustrator is not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy and paste or place the raster image into Illustrator.
2. Select the graphic with the Selection Tool (V), the first black arrow icon in the toolbar.
3. Hit the *Live Trace * (formerly *Image Trace*) button in the tool options along the top, then open the *Image Trace settings*
4. Set the mode to *Color*, then set the number of colours you want; 6 would be suitable for this graphic. In the Advanced options check the option "Ignore White". Then close the Image Trace settings dialog.
5. Hit the *Expand* button.
6. Ungroup the graphic. Now you can select and move the pieces, or change the fill colour.

[image]

If you want to make one of the rectangle shapes thicker, use *Effect > Path > Offset Path*

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm still trying to find "Image Trace" but I only see "Live Trace": https://i.stack.imgur.com/43G2G.png

Comment: It's not in the "Object" menu either: https://i.stack.imgur.com/amxk8.png

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf It's called Image Trace now in Illustrator CC.  "Live Trace" was its name in older versions.